# How long can I stay in France after my titre de séjour and récépissé have ended

Tags: working-visas, france

My titre de séjour ended 1st October, one month after my original work contract ended.

However, my contract was extended until the end of December, so I went to the prefecture (in September) to apply for a new titre de séjour.

Weirdly, they asked for more information, either a new contract past the 31st December or and attestation of the end of the contract and ability to receive employment benefits from the Pôle Emploi…

They gave me a récépissé valid until the 1st January. However, more contract finishes 31st December so they is no way I can be out of France by this time.

Questions

- How long can I remain in France after my after my titre de séjour and récépissé have ended?
- If I can't remain at all, can I extend the récépissé?
- Did they make a mistake in not granting me another titre de séjour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The prefectures have a tendency to do that when the duration of the contract extension is quite short...instead of giving you a new titre de séjour, they will just give you a récépissé until such time that you are able to show that you have a contract extension or have right to unemployment benefits (this is what the attestation pôle emploi is for). Technically, the préfecture should renew your right to stay in France for as long as you are entitled to unemployment benefits (I'm looking for a link to this, and I will edit my answer once I find it).

Regarding your questions:

- > How long can I remain in France after my after my titre de séjour and
  >   récépissé have ended?

Technically, once your tds and récépissé have expired and you did not undergo a process for extension/renewal, you are considered to be overstaying.

- > If I can't remain at all, can I extend the récépissé?

Similar to what I mentioned above, you should be able to renew your récépissé to at least sign up for pôle emploi and get unemployment benefits (note that you cannot sign up with pôle emploi until AFTER your contract expires). Once you get that, you need an *attestation* from pôle emploi saying you get unemployment benefits, and then they extend your titre de séjour.

Just to be clear, you need to have been working and paying into the system for unemployment benefits for at least 4 months in order to be entitled to avail of said benefits. 
 -

> Did they make a mistake in not granting me another titre de séjour?

Nope, I don't think so. With such a short period between the expiration of your current titre de séjour and the expiration of your current contract (3 months), they often just give a récépissé.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Immensely helpful. I did not know I could renew my récépissé.

Comment: I was never even given the récépissé and my TDS expired at the end of September. I submitted a renewal request before that happened. I'm told by my university that as long as your process is 'in progress' you 'should' be fine. They renew your récépissé up until they issue the TDS. I just wish I had one...

Comment: @lafemmecosmique I was told that too, but without the récépissé you can't get back into France if you leave (I guess you know that :). I found I had to bug the CNRS person responsible 3 or 4 times before they actually called the prefecture and made an appointment...