# Blue Card France

Tags: france, blue-card

I have seen plenty of answers for the the following question for Germany but I am specifically asking for France.

What happens if a person quits/losses their job in France after the initial 2 yrs but before the 3rd year. How long can they stay in the France looking for a job before they have to leave? What are the requirements on the new job?

I have seen conflicting answers on websites so I am sure there will be conflicting responses here as well. Thus, I would really appreciate of answers are supplemented with references of official websites or personal experiences.

Comment: @audionuma It's far from obvious, the most natural interpretation is that it is about the initial period of validity of the permit. Unfortunately, I don't know what the rules are but it would also make the rules for "passeport talent" much more restrictive than a regular "travailleur salarié" permit, which would be odd.

Comment: @Relaxed : comment deleted as it seems misleading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [answer](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/15053/blue-card-france/15090#15090) above is quite right. I am writing this to summarize my research into this as well as provide some extra references.

### European Blue Card and Job Change

The following two explain what is relevant for job change for European Blue Card holders:

[Article R5221-3 of the labor code](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichCodeArticle.do?idArticle=LEGIARTI000020562687&cidTexte=LEGITEXT000006072050) states that one can change jobs after two years as long as it is consistent with the rules for European Blue Card

> 2° La carte de séjour pluriannuelle portant la mention " passeport talent " délivrée en application des 1°, 2°, 3°, 4°, 9° et 10° de l'article L. 313-20 du code de l'entrée et du séjour des étrangers et du droit d'asile ou le visa de long séjour valant titre de séjour mentionné au 9° de l'article R. 311-3 du même code.
>
> Elle permet l'exercice de l'activité professionnelle salariée ayant justifié la délivrance du titre de séjour.
>
> Lorsqu'elle est délivrée en application du 1° et du 2° de l'article L. 313-20, elle autorise à exercer toute activité salariée à l'issue de sa deuxième année de validité sous réserve du respect de ses conditions de délivrance.

I am giving the relevant text from [Article L 313-20](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichCodeArticle.do;jsessionid=67760952EF89CCF216968C35B87924D5.tplgfr33s_2?cidTexte=LEGITEXT000006070158&idArticle=LEGIARTI000032166328&dateTexte=20181119&categorieLien=cid#LEGIARTI000032166328) to show that the above is referring to the European Blue Card

> 2° A l'étranger qui occupe un emploi hautement qualifié, pour une durée égale ou supérieure à un an, et justifie d'un diplôme sanctionnant au moins trois années d'études supérieures ou d'une expérience professionnelle d'au moins cinq ans d'un niveau comparable. Cette carte, d'une durée égale à celle figurant sur le contrat de travail, porte la mention " carte bleue européenne ".
>
> L'étranger qui justifie avoir séjourné au moins dix-huit mois dans un autre Etat membre de l'Union européenne sous couvert d'une " carte bleue européenne " obtient la même carte de séjour, sous réserve qu'il en fasse la demande dans le mois qui suit son entrée en France, sans que soit exigé le respect de la condition prévue à l'article L. 313-2 du présent code ;

### Status when one is in between jobs

There still remains the issue of what happens when one is without a job. This is a bit tricky. I give below what happens when one looses their job involuntarily (and what that means). However, it is not clear to me what happens if one quits their job [ar5975's answer](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/15053/blue-card-france/15090#15090) does state that if one quits they have to find a job 'quickly' but it's not clear to me how quick that has to be.

[Article L313-5-1](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichCodeArticle.do;jsessionid=67760952EF89CCF216968C35B87924D5.tplgfr33s_2?idArticle=LEGIARTI000032165954&cidTexte=LEGITEXT000006070158&dateTexte=20181113) states that an involuntary loss of job is not a reason to be out of status

> N'est pas regardé comme ayant cessé de remplir la condition d'activité prévue au 1° de l'article L. 313-10 et à l'article L. 313-20 l'étranger involontairement privé d'emploi au sens de ces mêmes articles.

Furthermore [L.313-20](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichCodeArticle.do;jsessionid=67760952EF89CCF216968C35B87924D5.tplgfr33s_2?cidTexte=LEGITEXT000006070158&idArticle=LEGIARTI000032166328&dateTexte=20181119&categorieLien=cid#LEGIARTI000032166328) also states that at the time of renewal if one is unemployed then the card is extended for the time left on the chômage

> Lorsqu'un étranger bénéficiaire de la carte de séjour pluriannuelle portant la mention " passeport talent " et exerçant une activité salariée prévue aux 1°, 2° et 4° du présent article se trouve involontairement privé d'emploi à la date du renouvellement de sa carte, celle-ci est renouvelée pour une durée équivalente à celle des droits qu'il a acquis à l'allocation d'assurance mentionnée à l'article L. 5422-1 du code du travail.

Finally [this article](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/eli/arrete/2018/5/3/MTRD1803345A/jo/article_snum1) states what is considered an involuntary loss of employment

> « Art. 2. - Sont involontairement privés d'emploi ou assimilés, les salariés dont la cessation du contrat de travail résulte :
>
> - d'un licenciement ;
> - d'une rupture conventionnelle du contrat de travail, au sens des articles L. 1237-11 et >suivants du code du travail ;
> - d'une rupture d'un commun accord du contrat de travail, au sens des articles L. 1237-17 >et suivants du code du travail ;
> - d'une fin de contrat de travail à durée déterminée dont notamment le contrat à objet >défini, ou de contrat de mission ;
> - d'une rupture anticipée d'un contrat de travail à durée déterminée, dont notamment le >contrat à objet défini, ou d'un contrat de mission, à l'initiative de l'employeur ;
> - d'une démission considérée comme légitime, dans les conditions fixées par un accord >d'application ;
> - d'une rupture de contrat de travail résultant de l'une des causes énoncées à l'article >L. 1233-3 du code du travail ».

Answer (score 2):

I will try my best to answer your question:

1. The European blue card in France is linked to the multi-year resident permit (the *"titre de séjour pluriannuel")* called the "passeport talent" ([see number 2 of the article L313-20 in the French code for foreigners or CESEDA](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichCodeArticle.do?cidTexte=LEGITEXT000006070158&idArticle=LEGIARTI000032166328&dateTexte=&categorieLien=cid)), thus it has the same conditions. You cannot change jobs until AFTER the 2nd year of your *titre de séjour* ([this is according to R5221-3 of the labor code](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichCodeArticle.do?idArticle=LEGIARTI000020562687&cidTexte=LEGITEXT000006072050))
2. [The same labor code article states that once you have gone beyond the two years](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichCodeArticle.do?idArticle=LEGIARTI000020562687&cidTexte=LEGITEXT000006072050), you can technically change jobs, as long as it fulfills the same conditions for the first European blue card:

> Lorsqu'elle est délivrée en application du 1° et du 2° de l'article L. 313-20, elle autorise à exercer toute activité salariée à l'issue de sa deuxième année de validité sous réserve du respect de ses conditions de délivrance.

in English

> If delivered under no. 1 or 2. of article L313-20 [of the CESEDA], it authorizes all employment after the second year of its validity, as long as it respects the conditions of delivery [of the European blue card]

3. If you lost your job involuntarily (i.e. you were fired), you are entitled to unemployment benefits...and this allows you to stay in France (this is according to some posts on the website of an association that helps foreigners called "Assouevam"). The entitlement to unemployment benefits allow you to renew your *titre de séjour* (I cannot find an appropriate link to this right now, but will edit once I find it but alluded to this in another post here: [How long can I stay in France after my titre de séjour and récépissé have ended](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/14916/how-long-can-i-stay-in-france-after-my-titre-de-s%C3%A9jour-and-r%C3%A9c%C3%A9piss%C3%A9-have-ended/14917?noredirect=1#comment25523_14917)). Should you resign, however, then you are not entitled to unemployment benefits, in which case you'd need to find another related job right away in order to continue fufilling the requirements.
4. Thus, based on what I've read online (and experiences of other people posted in other groups), you are allowed to stay in France until the expiration of your *titre de séjour*. However, you must note that when given this type of *titre de séjour* you may be subject to checks/verification by the prefecture to see if you still fulfill the conditions of the delivery of the *titre de séjour*. Thus, if you change jobs after the 2nd year, the new job still has to fulfill the requirements of the European blue card (highly-qualified job, 3 years study or at least 5 years work experience, salary of something like €53 000 per annum, etc.)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Why “technically”? It's indeed possible to stay in France if you lose your job involuntarily on a regular working permit (and not merely “technically”), see https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F15898 But why do you think your other answer or what you have read online applies here? The important thing is that the Blue Card/Passeport talent rests on an entirely different legal basis. The real question is therefore whether these rules also apply, as the relevant language is missing in the relevant service-public.fr pages and I could not find anything in the law either.

Comment: I say technically because there can be instances of a "chicken and egg situation" where this becomes complicated: your titre de séjour is going to expire on or around the time you lose your job. One of the requirements to sign up to the unemployment office (pôle emploi), get the benefits, and more importantly get an "attestation" to have a valid titre de séjour (either a normal salarié or passeport talent work). In order to get the titre de séjour or at least a récépissé, you need the attestation from pôle emploi.

Comment: Should you not be entitled to unemployment benefits (e.g. you resign) then you would need to find a another job that also fulfills the conditions to get a blue card/passeport talent. if you do not, and you are subjected to a check by the prefecture (which is a possibility with the new multi-year cards), they can take away your right to stay in France.

Comment: How do you know a “passeport talent” works? It makes sense but I haven't been able to find a single source or example confirming that.

Comment: For the rest, I still don't think “technically” is the right way to put it. I get there can be timing issues but generally speaking, you're entitled to it, period. And of course, if you resign and/or find another job, you're outside of the scope of this rule.

Comment: @Relaxed: what do you mean exactly by 'how do you know if a "passeport talent" works'? As for the word "technically," I'm removing it from my answer since it seems that it causes confusion.

Comment: I was referring to “(either a normal salarié or passeport talent work)”. I would like to find some confirmation that you are allowed to stay and/or renew your residence permit after losing your job involuntarily while on a “passeport talent” card. The language describing this is conspicuously absent on the service-public.fr page regarding “passeport talent”, whereas it's there on the page regarding a regular ”travailleur salarié” permit.

Comment: Oh ok. Based on what I found, article L313-10 of the CESEDA mentions specifically that the "salarié" card allows you to renew your card of you have the right to unemployment benefits (I quote: "La carte de séjour est prolongée d'un an si l'étranger se trouve involontairement privé d'emploi. Lors du renouvellement suivant, s'il est toujours privé d'emploi, il est statué sur son droit au séjour pour une durée équivalente à celle des droits qu'il a acquis à l'allocation d'assurance mentionnée à l'article L. 5422-1 du code du travail"). Unable to find text specific to the blue card though.

Comment: Yes, I knew that for the regular “travailleur salarié” card. I have not been to confirm it applies to the blue card, otherwise I would have posted an answer earlier. I was curious whether you had some specific example where it worked.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85805/discussion-between-ar5975-and-relaxed).

Comment: Since I'm relatively new to Stackexchange, I wanted to find out what the downvote to my answer means? I saw a -15 pop up in the notifications...and would like to know why it was downvoted so that I can improve my answer.

Comment: Your answer has not been downvoted (with enough experience I am able to see that) but it has been “un-accepted”. FunkyPhyzz accepted his or her own answer below (I don't think he gets the +15 because it's his or her own answer but if it would have been someone else's, the 15-point bonus would have been transferred).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @Relaxed. I did not see that in my profile.